# What's the "right way" to embed a UITextField inside a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I'm trying to build a form for my iOS app with a grouped UITableView. I want to create a prototype cell in Interface Builder that has a UITextField in it, but I want it to look like a basic UITableViewCell, i.e.:

1. Have the same indentation as the leading space in a basic UITableViewCell (currently it's 15 points)
2. Have zero top and bottom spaces
3. Have the same size as a default cell (currently 44 points)

I can solve 1 and 2 by creating constraints with the right constants (a UITextField with no border has an 8 point padding on every side), but it would be better to implement it in a way that wouldn't force me to update the numbers whenever Apple changes the default look. Another problem I have is with 3: if I add constraints between the cell's content view and the text field, the result is that the height of the cell shrinks, instead of staying with the default size.

The only solution I found so far for 1 is to create a dummy basic cell, set a non-empty string as its label, trigger layout and then read the numbers back. It's quite a hack... I don't know how to programmatically get the padding of a text field.

So, what's the "right way" to do this (preferably in IB)?